# Cannot DELETE or UPDATE row in Google BigQuery due to a timestamp for a field being outside the range of Standard SQL timestamp

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In Google BigQuery, I have a timestamp field which has the year 20195. This is ofcourse causing errors as it's outside the Standard SQL Timestamp range. However I cannot update this records or delete this record as the error, even by using SAFE_CAST. For example, i've tried:

```
UPDATE [table] SET DateField = SAFE_CAST('2019-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' AS TIMESTAMP)...
```

"Cannot return an invalid timestamp value of 575129030400000000 microseconds relative to the Unix epoch." pops up. I know how to SELECT and return a null instead of an error using Safe-Cast, but cannot use this to update/delete.

Question is: How can I **delete or update** this field successfully with out any errors?

Comment: Please show the query where you are having the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `safe.` prefix to return `NULL` instead:

```
select safe.timestamp_micros(575129030400000000)
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I can use safe. to read, but it’s updating or deleting the row that’s tricky,

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to microseconds (which doesn't result in a bounds check) and then attempt to convert back, deleting the row if the safe conversion results in NULL:

```
DELETE dataset.table
WHERE ts IS NOT NULL
  AND SAFE.TIMESTAMP_MICROS(UNIX_MICROS(ts)) IS NULL
```

Or if you want to set such values to NULL instead:

```
UPDATE dataset.table
SET ts = SAFE.TIMESTAMP_MICROS(UNIX_MICROS(ts))
WHERE true
```

Comment: Thanks Elliott, but I get the same error : Cannot return an invalid timestamp value of ...

Comment: With both queries? Do you have more than one timestamp column?

Comment: Yes with both queries, there’s a few more time stamp columns, but they’re not a problem, I’ve checked and it’s just this 1 column with a bad TimeStamp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repair bad values using `UPDATE` you have to apply it across the whole table, using a conditional. Elliot's answer is correct but I can't can't comment or upvote so I'll elaborate slightly and answer this question:

```
UPDATE `my.table` 
SET DateField = IF(SAFE.DATE(DateField) IS NULL AND DateField IS NOT NULL, TIMESTAMP('2019-01-01 00:00:00 UTC'), DateField)
WHERE true
```

The `WHERE true` is the secret sauce, which isn't obvious from Elliot's answer. If you try to do `WHERE id = 1234` or whatever it will continue to give the same error. `SAFE.DATE` is a concise way of checking for valid dates and will return `NULL` if they are invalid, however your field may be nullable which is why I have added the null check.